# MS Access Query, criteria to show all records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access 2010 wizard query in order to filter table. 

**What I want to get as a result** is a table which returns data base on: 
- today's date of the week    
- User who is working on it (users: AAA,BBB,DDD in the following table).

**Example table looks like this:**

```
Monday | Tuesday
AAA    | BBB 
AAA    | BBB 
DDD    | AAA
DDD    | AAA
```

**Results I want i would be** 

If today is Monday, I want data for AAA

```
Monday | Tuesday
AAA    | BBB 
AAA    | BBB
```

If today is Tuesday, I want data for AAA

```
Monday | Tuesday
DDD    | AAA
DDD    | AAA
```

**My idea so far:** 

In a criteria field I put a condition:

```
IIf([TempVars]![WorkingDay]=2,[TempVars]![WorkingUser],*)
```

My understanding is: 
-> if today is 2nd day (Tuesday) then show data for AAA, otherwise (it is not Tuesday) show all.

I checked TempVars (calculated when access base is opened) and they are correct and are equal: 
[TempVars]![WorkingDay]=2        
[TempVars]![WorkingUser]=AAA

That actually works -> I see records for AAA, however if today is not Tuesday (TempVar = 1) I would like to see all records (compilator should go into false statement which is "*", but I actually don't see any records ... Compilator goes into false statement and if I manually insert "BBB" I will get BBB, but **I don't know what should I type into, so i get all data.**

I am not sure what is wrong with that statement, I tried instead of " * ", putting: 
- Like(" * ")    
- Like " * "   
- (Is not null) Or (is null)  

In Access it presents like this:
[Screen from Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcoHm.png)

SQL code, generated by Access:

```
SELECT
t001.Monday, t001.Tuesday
FROM
 Tbl_001_WholeBase AS t001
WHERE
 (((t001.Monday)=IIf([tempvars]![WorkingDay]=1,[tempvars]![WorkingUser],"*")) AND ((t001.Tuesday)=IIf([tempvars]![WorkingDay]=2,[tempvars]![WorkingUser],"*")));
```

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider normalising your data such that the weekday is represented using a `Weekday` field, as opposed to having a separate field for each day of the week.

Nevertheless, the following query uses the `Choose` function to obtain the desired result:

```
select
    t001.Monday, t001.Tuesday
from
    tbl_001_wholebase t001
where
    choose
    (
        [tempvars]![WorkingDay],
        t001.Monday  = [tempvars]![WorkingUser],
        t001.Tuesday = [tempvars]![WorkingUser]
    )
```

Alternatively, using logical operators:

```
select
    t001.Monday, t001.Tuesday
from
    tbl_001_wholebase t001
where
    ([tempvars]![WorkingDay] = 1 and t001.Monday  = [tempvars]![WorkingUser]) or
    ([tempvars]![WorkingDay] = 2 and t001.Tuesday = [tempvars]![WorkingUser])
```

The reason that your query fails to return the desired results is because the `*` wildcard character should be used in conjunction with the `like` operator, not the `=` operator.